# Find basis of image and basis of Kernel of linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Sorry if similar questions have been asked before but I don't really understand them.
Question:

Let $T$ be a linear operator in $\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$ such that

$T\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},\quad T\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix} = 0,\quad T\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix},\quad T\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\3\\2\end{pmatrix} = 0$

Find a basis of the image of $T$, and find a basis of the kernel of $T$

I'm not really sure where to even start, any help appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Check that the four input vectors are a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$. Use that to describe the kernel (in order to find its basis). Use the fact that if $S$ spans $V$ and $T\colon V\to W$ is a linear transformation, then $T(S)$ spans the image; and any spanning set of a subspace contains a basis for that subspace.

Comment: What is your understanding of the meanings of “kernel” and “image?”

Comment: This is pretty simple. You have $Tv_1 = w_1$, $Tv_2=w_2$, $Tv_3 = 0$, $Tv_4 = 0$. Hence, $v_3$ and $v_4$ are in the kernel and every linear combination of them will be. Now, check if you can nontrivially linearly combine $w_1$ and $w_2$ to get the zero vector. If not, they are linearly independent and $\ker T = \operatorname{span}\{v_3,v_4\}$. By the rank-nullity formula, the image is then two-dimensional and will be spanned by $w_1$ and $w_2$.

Comment: @amsmath Before you start applying all those results, you need to ensure that $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin True. But if it wasn't a basis, the exercise couldn't be done.

Comment: @amsmath: Plenty of incorrectly-stated problems lying around. In any case, it needs to be checked when it isn't obvious (here, I would posit it isn't obvious), not simply assumed because otherwise the problem would be ill-posed... for all we know, the problem could be ill-posed.